# UNITY3D:can someone help me to convert this from pc to mobile platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine

im getting this error on mobile platform: 'GetComponent' is not a member of 'Object' when on mobile flatform, but works fine on windows. please help me resolving this problem. advance thanks. :D

```
for (stage = 2; stage <= cells.length; stage++) 

{

for (i = 0; i <= cells.length - 1; i++) 

{ 



if (doorsToCells[i] == stage - 1)

for (var checkDoor : GameObject in cells[i].GetComponent(AIpathCellScript).… /*is is the line with error*/

{

if (checkDoor != gameObject)

{

for (var checkCell : GameObject in checkDoor.GetComponent(AIpathDoorScript)…

{

for (var j : int = 0; j <= cells.length - 1; j++)

{

if (cells[j] == checkCell && doorsToCells[j] == null)

doorsToCells[j] = stage;

}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to cast your variables to the types you want... in this case to a GameObject

second your loop seems wrong... you are looping for gameobjects inside a script component which is really weird..(unless you are not showing all of your code)